# Right NavBar Button item disappears after pushing view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So we got a Nav Controller with a UITableView for the RootViewController. Then when the user clicks the table cell, we push an EKEventController onto the Nav stack and display details for  the event represented by the table cell.

I am trying to add a button on the right side, but it does not show up.

I'm adding the button when the user clicks the table cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  

    // Upon selecting an event, create an EKEventViewController to display the event.
    self.detailViewController = [[[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]autorelease];            
    detailViewController.event = [self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailViewController.allowsEditing = NO;  
    UIBarButtonItem *locationMapViewButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                  initWithTitle:@"Map"
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                         target:self 
                                                         action:@selector(showMap:)];  
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = locationMapViewButtonItem;  
    [locationMapViewButtonItem release];  
    UITableView *eventTableView = [[self.detailViewController.view subviews]objectAtIndex:0];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

The right bar button disappears when the EKEvent controller shows up however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the navigation item of the view controller being pushed, so your line:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = locationMapViewButtonItem;
```

Should become:

```
detailViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = locationMapViewButtonItem;
```

Comment: It just dawned on my what might of gone wrong. The application is a TabController -> three Navs -> ViewControllers. The MainWindow nib contains the Window, TabController, and three Nav objects. The root controllers have their nibs coded in through IB, but there are no references to them in the AppDel. My understanding was the ViewController's Navs can be referenced through the "Nav" property, but under the debugger, I couldn't find it. My guess is since they were instanciated through the nib, there is no references to their nav stack? I'll have to do **A LOT** of reading up on these nib files.

Comment: @studev's answer is correct. each view controller pushed into a navigation controller has its own navigationItem which needs to be configured. You can do this in IB or programmatically.